# Making a Gripper Changer for a Robotic Arm

Tags: robotic-arm

How do you make a gripper changer for a robotic arm like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8ovd4khIBM)? I don't see how you could connect power/control wires or what you use to hold the gripper to the arm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanically, there are a variety of ways to fix the gripper to the arm.  I think the easiest way is to have a little tab rotate under an overhang.

At least one of the grippers shown in your video is pneumatic.  (It is quite possible both are).  In which case, the pneumatic connection is just a hole with a gasket or O-ring to seal it.

Electrically, you can have pins on a connector slide into the housing on the other end.  But i think that requires some pretty tight tolerances, and might wear out quickly.  More likely, you can use something called "pogo pins".  these are spring loaded contacts made for just this type of thing.

it is also possible that your end-effector gripper can be actuated mechanically.  this can be accomplished with gears, splines, or push rods i think.